# /usr/sbin/nologin & GUI login

Tags: command-line, login

I have an account with `/usr/bin/nologin` as the login shell.
If I try to `su` to that account, I get the message:

```
This account is currently not available
```

as expected.

In `/etc/lightdm/users.conf`, I hide all the users' names from the login GUI so all users have to type both their user name and password.

The problem is that account with the `/usr/sbin/nologin` shell can login using the GUI by inputing the right credentials (User Name+Password).

Removing the account home folder prevents GUI login but this creates another set of problems such as applications failing to launch.

How do I prevent GUI login for this account?

Comment: Lock the account: `passwd -l username`.

Comment: Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more.  ;-)  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Comment: I do not see any option to convert muru's reply to an answer (the answer is in the comment section?). But I confirm that locking the account as suggested by muru prevents GUI login. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Answer copied from comments:

Just lock the account by using:

```
passwd -l username
```